# Cannot get R to use any libraries even after reinstall

Tags: r

I would really appreciate any help as I seem to have completely broken R on my computer. I am learning R for class so I am still fairly new. I am running windows with new downloads of the latest version of both r and rStudio. I have uninstalled R, rStudio, and rTools, in addition to deleting the r folders in documents and app data. After installing just R and rStudio, I attempt to install ggplot2 and get the following.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/RNew/R-4.0.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

During startup -

```
Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/RNew/R-4.0.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
> install.packages("ggplot2")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/brnfr/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4067683 bytes (3.9 MB)
downloaded 3.9 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\brnfr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiqACJ2\downloaded_packages

> library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/RNew/R-4.0.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: `stats` not found? Ouch. My first step would be to uninstall and reinstall R from scratch. (If you've managed your projects and user-installed packages correctly, then this should not produce a big problem.)

Comment: Unfortunately I've already uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times and tried in new directories as well. The same issue continues to occur. I am still learn r and have saved my script separately, but at this point I just need R to work at all.

Comment: Look for `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` files, both in your `HOME` directory (likely `c:/Users/brnfr/Documents/` or `c:/Users/brnfr/`), move them out of the way. Lacking that ... sorry, no idea, `stats` should always be available for an interactive R session.

Comment: This worked thanks! I deleted these and the rest of the r folders/files I could find then reinstalled.